# Install4j: Overriding default rollback

Tags: java, install4j

I am building my Installer using install4j 6.1.4. I have added an `InstallerEventListener` to the context for `EventType.CANCELLING` for adding manual rollback functions. But I believe this does not override the default rollback function of Install4j.

For some debug issue my customers require the "Failed installation" to conditionally stay as it is. Which means the customer would like to choose whether to perform the rollback or not.

Currently, I am using `Util.showOptionDialog()` inside the custom rollback. Even though if the user wants to keep the installation as it is and the rollback method does not do anything, the default rollback from install4j cleans up the installation.

Is there any way I can override/ diactivate the default rollback?

Answer (score 0):

As of 6.1.5 there is no way to dynamically add rollback barriers while the rollback is in progress. I've added this feature request to the issue tracker.

Comment: what do you mean by dynamically add rollback barrier?

Comment: The rollback barrier attributes on actions and screens prevent any further rollback beyond that point, but they are fixed at runtime. You would like to dynamically add such a barrier for the action where you show the question dialog, depending on the answer of the user.

Comment: The question has to be asked to the user exactly before starting the rollback, not at the start of the installation. But again, asking at the beginning can also be another possible solution.

Comment: I have scheduled such a feature for 7.0.